# cp: /javascripts/phonegap.js: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

PhoneGap is not installed in my mac. Now, I want to run a PhoneGap project with Xcode and I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me how to run the PhoneGap project in Xcode? I want to run the project from [Junkyard-Jumbotron](http://c4fcm.github.io/Junkyard-Jumbotron/).

Comment: That is a very old project and a lot of things changes in the last years. If you want to run it on an actual device/iOS you have to rewrite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, have you checked in the file directory to see if the file exists? Make sure you have met all of the requirements.

```
install the following:
   - Xcode 4.3+
   - Xcode Command Line Tools
   - Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Lion or greater (10.7+)
   - Necessary for installing on device:
    -----Apple iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)
    -----iOS developer certificate

Install the iOS SDK and Apache Cordova

   - Install Xcode from the Mac App Store or Apple Developer Downloads
  -  Install the Xcode Command Line Tools (Xcode Preferences -> Downloads -> Components -> Command Line Tools -> Install).
   - Download the latest release of [Apache PhoneGap
    -----extract its contents
    -----Apache Cordova iOS is found under lib/ios
    Install CordovaLib

-Download the Cordova source
-Extract to source to their final permanent location on your hard drive (for example, to ~/Documents/CordovaLib-2.X.X)
```

- There is no step 3

Here is the link to getting started on a new project:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Comment: I already did that and it's working for the fresh project, not in the one, I downloaded from here - https://github.com/c4fcm/Junkyard-Jumbotron.